# SSO with JWT and multiple user accounts + SPA

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have two web applications `app.domain1.com` which is a SPA with his own API on `api.domain1.com` and `app.domain2.com`) with each have their own authentication system and user accounts
and I need to authenticate the user from app.domain1.com from app.domain2.com. The goal is to simplify switching from one app to another without requiring the user to log into each application by re-entering their password. I'm the owner of one app only so It's not possible to put them behind a reverse proxy or so.

**Example :**

`app.domain2.com` redirect to `app.domain1.com/connect/{JWT}` -> `app.domain1.com` SPA extract the JWT and send it via ajax to `api.domain1.com` for validation and login.

I have looking for OAuth2 and OpenID Connect for these but OAuth2 is more about delegation of resource access than authentication and OpenID Connect needs an Identity Provider which seems incompatible with my use case where each app has his own authentication mecanism and where I could not add a central authentication server.
Ideally, I'd like to adhere to a standard protocol.

I thought I could expose an endpoint GET /connect/{JWT} on each app.
The JWT could contains an email which could identify the user account, app.domain1.com and app.domain2.com could then share the secret for validating the JWT has not be tampered
and could have a short validity duration.

This endpoint validate the JWT, verify if a user match the email inside the JWT and log the user in.

I'm not sure about the security considerations with these process and if there is any other options ?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should go with OIDC. That protocol is designed exactly for the feature you described here. You can have one of the apps act as the IdP, and the other will be a Relying Party. It depends on which technology you use for your apps, but in some languages there are libraries which will turn your app into an IdP.

You can think of some generic protocol to make that federated login work, but you will be better off using standards. This way you won't have to wonder what are the security implications for your solution - you have security considerations for OIDC described in the spec itself.